# Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: ...\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Tags: flutter, android-studio, adb, daemon

When I start the project popup shows "Flutter daemon terminate" and when starting the flutter application it shows the "No Connected Devices Found" dialog box. Then I run `flutter doctor -v` doctor found issues in:

```
Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
X Exception: Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: C:\Users\Pulsara\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
• #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
  #1      AndroidDevices.pollingGetDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device_discovery.dart:78:7)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #2      PollingDeviceDiscovery._populateDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:413:54)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #3      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #4      DeviceManager.getAllConnectedDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:170:40)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #5      DeviceValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:515:34)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #6      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:24)
  <asynchronous suspension>
```

I already set up the SDK path as ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS in user variables and `tools`, and `platform-tools` in Path. And reinstalled the `platform-tools` as well but did not solve the issue. I cannot figure the solution if anyone can give me a solution it will be really appreciated.

Tis below log displays in the Event Log:

```
12/2/2021
12:26 AM    'C:\Users\Pulsara\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform- 
tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

12:26 AM    'C:\Users\Pulsara\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform- 
tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

12:26 AM    * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

12:26 AM    * daemon started successfully

12:26 AM    Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly 
closed by the remote host

12:26 AM    Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
```

I still couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: Try deleting this folder C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Android

Comment: Try installing Android studio beta.

Comment: I have done those steps but still not fixed.

Comment: Is there any issue regarding `tcp :5037` port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this step after not working on any of the steps I mentioned in the question.

The problem was in the antivirus program. It denied access to starting the flutter daemon on `port 5037`. I simply uninstalled the antivirus program from my device. Then it works like a charm.

Comment: You need to add android folder in AppData, android installation, jdk and gradle to windows defender and antivirus exclusion.